# How to pass custom data into teams task module from bot adaptive card

Tags: node.js, microsoft-teams

I have a teams bot (nodejs) that renders an adaptive card with some table data. We want to provide a richer data viewing experience by iframing a javascript widget inside of a task module that will display the data using interactive D3 charts.

Basically the adaptive card will have a "see more" button, which will invoke a task module containing the html contents.

The part I can't figure out is how to access the data from the html inside the task module. I realize that there is a global object called `microsoftTeams` that contains metadata and context, but it doesn't seem specific to the adaptive card that was clicked (the adaptive card that invoked the task module). It has much more global info used for teams such as the user and conversation metadata.

I was able to insert the data into the `taskInfo` object when invoking the task module as a custom param. So my question is, is there a way to access the `taskInfo` object from inside the HTML iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using query strings to get data from the server to the client (There might be a better way, hopefully @Saonti-MSFT comes back with an easier/cleaner way).

This is my task object:

```js
task: {
  type: "continue",
  value: {
    url: `${process.env.HostName}?message=${JSON.stringify(Buffer.from(message).toString("base64"))}`,
    width: 500, 
    height: 736
  },
}
```

On the client side I then get the search query and convert it back do the following

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const message = urlParams.get('message');

// Needed to remove the quotes and convert spaces to "+" as this was getting lost
const data = atob(message.replace(/"/g,"").replace(/\s/g, "+"));
```

**NOTE:** I was only doing this for a single string, but I don't see why would couldn't use an object if you converted it to a string on the server then parsed it on the client.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry for the late response. It does seem like this was/is the only way to do it, so that is the approach I took. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this [Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module). Here you have HTML pages which can be customized. You can create your own webpages and integrate in the task module.

Comment: I was looking at the JS version, but I can't see anywhere in the sample where data in the task info is being used on the HTML page?

Comment: Do you have an example of the custom data being using on the HTML page inside the iframe @Saonti-MSFT please?

Comment: @Ghojzilla - When you submit the task module The submitHandler function resides in the TaskInfo.url web page. Please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-tabs#submitting-the-result-of-a-task-module)?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT - My understanding of the submit handler is this is called when `microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask` is called from the web page. Not to pass data from the server to the client, like a string. (I have submitted an answer which might make what I mean a little clearer). Are you able to pass data from the server to the webpage using the submit handler? Does the webpage have access to the submit handler function to pull data out?